# PHP adding one file aaray in anothe file

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, invoice

my sale receipt file does not contain the product unit price which i was fetching from the product page file but while adding the product unit price array in sale file. i am unable to view the sale receipt.

here is the product unit price array i am adding in sale file.

```
<td class="text-right"><span class="display_currency" data-currency_symbol="false">{{ $purchase_line->pp_without_discount}}</span></td>
```

Comment: It's hard to understand the question can you give more details ?

Comment: in my sale invoice file to display value i use -- $sell-> (example) | example to display quantity in invoice i use <td>
                <span class="display_currency" data-currency_symbol="true">{{ $sell_line->quantity }}</span>
            </td>

Comment: but i cannot use another file array in sale file for example if i have to fetch product price array from product file to sale file

Comment: i guess you have to compact that array you want to use to the exact view needed
--
does $purchase_line is defined in the controller and has the value pp_without_discount in it ?

Comment: it is define in controller and same array display correct value in product page but its unable to display value in sale file